# How can I tell when data has been received with NSURLConnection?

Tags: php, ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I'm working on a Swift application that uses a PHP web service to query a database. One issue - I have no idea how to tell when data has been received in the model class, so I can't update the view! How can I tell if the connection has finished, then update said view? For this purpose, I've created a dummy label called text. Thanks for the help in advance, and happy holidays!

User.swift

```
import Foundation

class User: NSObject {

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var email: String?

    var recievedJSON: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var userData: [[String: String]]!

    var verified: Bool = false

    required init(username: String, password: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, username: String, password: String, email: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
    }

    func attemptRegister() {
        var variables: [String] = ["firstname=" + self.firstName! + "&"]
        variables.append("lastname=" + self.lastName! + "&")
        variables.append("username=" + self.username + "&")
        variables.append("password=" + self.password + "&")
        variables.append("email=" + self.email!)
        request("https://codekaufman.com/register.php", variables: variables)
    }

    func attemptSignIn() {
        var variables: [String] = ["username=" + self.username + "&"]
        variables.append("password=" + self.password)
        request("https://codekaufman.com/login.php", variables: variables)
        println("Attempting sign-in...")
    }

    private func request(urlPath: String, variables: [String]?) {
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        if(variables != nil) {
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            var bodyData: NSString = ""
            for item in variables! {
                bodyData = bodyData + NSString(string: item)
            }

            request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        }

        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
        connection.start()
        println("Connection started.")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
        self.recievedJSON.appendData(data)
        println("Possible data recieved.")
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        userData = parseJSON(recievedJSON)

        if(userData != nil) {
            println("Data recieved:")
            println(userData[0])
            self.firstName = userData[0]["first_name"]
            self.lastName = userData[0]["last_name"]
        } else {
            println("No data recieved.")
        }

    }

    func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> [[String: String]]? {
        var error: NSError?
        var userData: [[String: String]]!
        userData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? [[String: String]]

        #if DEBUG

        if (userData != nil) {
            println("NSData had data, printing and returning.")
            println(userData)
        } else {
            println("NSData empty, returning nil.")
        }

        #endif

        return userData
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(seque: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

    @IBAction func signin(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(username.text == "" || password.text == "") {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Credentials", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            var attempt: User = User(username: username.text, password: password.text)
            attempt.attemptSignIn()
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Edit: Based on previous comments/answers, I feel I should clarify. Data is being received. But it takes a few seconds, so how can I signify to the view controller that the data has been received, and the process is finished?

Comment: didReceiveData isn't being called?

Comment: You can send a notification in `connectionDidFinishLoading` that the view controller has registered for.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean as an answer so I can accredit you?

Comment: Look at [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

Comment: Not really an answer, but a couple of observations. I wouldn't have a model be responsible for creating itself. There should be another object that handles getting data from a server and parsing the response to create model objects. An advantage of this is that you then have a different object that knows when model objects have been created and you can handle that appropriately. Secondly - NSURLSession is a better choice than NSURLConnection these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a notification in the view controller with:

```
func addObserverForName(_ name: String?, object obj: AnyObject?, queue queue: NSOperationQueue?, usingBlock block: (NSNotification!) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol
```

Be sure to remove it in deinit:

```
func removeObserver(_ notificationObserver: AnyObject)
```

Send the notification from `connectionDidFinishLoading` using:

```
func postNotificationName(_ notificationName: String, object notificationSender: AnyObject?, userInfo userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)
```